# MapReduce - Count the document number a word apears

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new in MapRecude and trying to extend the word count program. I want to count in how many documents a word appears.
Example: If i have 3 documents and the word "Try" apears 3 times in document 1 and 5 times in document 3. I want the final count to be 2.

I am not really sure how to do this, i have tried the writablecomparable class as a Key in my mapper, but i am getting errors when i try to replace the key with the class so i abandoned it. I am currently trying to have a Text variable for the Key, and give the value "word + Document Name".

Here is what i have so far

**CODE**

```
    import java.io.DataInput;
    import java.io.DataOutput;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.*;
    
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
    
    public class wcount {
        public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
            private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
            private Text word = new Text();
            private Text fileName = new Text();
            
            private String tokens = "[_|$#<>\\^=\\[\\]\\*/\\\\,;,.\\-:()?!\"”“]";
            
            public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                String cleanValue = value.toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll(tokens, " ");
                
                String filePathString = ((FileSplit) reporter.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName().toString();
                fileName.set(new Text(filePathString));
                
                String line = cleanValue.toString();
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
                while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                    Text k = new Text(word + " " + fileName);
                    output.collect(k, one);
                }
            }
        }
    
        public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {         
            public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                String[] new_key = key.toString().split(" ");
                
                Text word = new Text();
                Text FileName = new Text();
                
                word.set(new_key[0]);
                //FileName.set(new_key[1]); //error here
                
                int sum = 0;
                while (values.hasNext()) {
                    sum += values.next().get();
                }
                output.collect(FileName, new IntWritable(sum));
            }
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            
            JobConf conf = new JobConf(wcount.class);
            conf.setJobName("wcount");
    
            conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
            
            conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
            conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
            conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    
            conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
            conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
    
            conf.setNumReduceTasks(1);
    
            FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
    
            JobClient.runJob(conf);
        }
    }
```

In my reducer trying to seperate the key in 2 strings but the "FileName.set(new_key[1]);" in giving me **out of Bounds Exception**.

I want to know if its possibol to do this with 1 run of MapReduce or i have to have a second. An example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Clearly `key.toString().split(" ")` doesn't contain what you think it does. For example, what if `key` is an empty string? Or has no spaces to split on?

Comment: Also, `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*` is a deprecated package. You should be importing from `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` (or just migrate to Spark)

Comment: I get that its emty when i am trying to split it in the reducer, but i dont get it because i am adding the space or tab in the output Text in the mapper.

Comment: Dunno what to say other than you should simply check the length of the values array before you try to extract parts of the string array. You can also simply print the data and look at the YARN UI for the logged output to further debug the problem. Since we don't have your input document, it's difficult to help any further

Answer (score 1):

Validate your inputs

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {         
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        String[] new_key = key.toString().split("\\s");
        if (new_key.length >= 2) {
            int sum = 0;
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                sum += values.next().get();
            }
            output.collect(new Text(new_key[1]), new IntWritable(sum));
         } 
     } else {
         System.out.printf("Unexpected data: \"%s\"%n", key);
     } 
}
```

You might also want to consider using LongWritable for large counts, or a Text output from a BigInteger value

Comment: Thanks for the anwser it helped me, but after all i ended up having the key as the word and the document as the value, so i didnt need to use split.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the code for anyone having the same problem.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;

public class wcount {
    
    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
        //private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();
        private Text fileName = new Text();
        
        private String tokens = "[_|$#<>\\^=\\[\\]\\*/\\\\,;,.\\-:()?!\"”“]";
        
        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String cleanValue = value.toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll(tokens, " ");
            
            String filePathString = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName().toString();
            fileName.set(new Text(filePathString));
            
            String line = cleanValue.toString();
            
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                context.write(word, fileName);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        
        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {          
            String tempWord = "";
            IntWritable tempvalue = new IntWritable(0);
            
            int sum = 0;
            for (Text value : values) {
                if(!value.toString().trim().equals(tempWord)) {
                    sum += 1;
                    tempWord = value.toString().trim();
                }
            }
            
            tempvalue.set(sum);
            context.write(key, tempvalue);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Doccount");
        job.setJarByClass(wcount.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        FileInputFormat .setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        System.out.println(success);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused what your reducer is actually counting. The first loop checks if `tempWord` is not an empty string. Then the next iterations compare that the next `value` does not equal the previous non-empty value? So, if you had more than one equal consecutive values, you're only going to count the first (order matters). If you want to properly count without ordering, you should insert all (non-empty) value strings into a HashSet, and take the length of that.

Comment: I could have set the `tempword` to the first value before the first loop and just start the for loop from `values+1`. My goal here is to get in how many different Documents the word exists. Because i found that in the reducer the input is sorted out, i just said if the first `value` is `Document1` and so is the second, then i am not counting the second one.

Comment: Oh, I see your filenames are the values now rather than the words. Still, I don't think it's safe to say the filename values will always be sorted, and if you want to count once per filename, I still think collecting values iterator into a Set and taking its length would make more sense

Comment: Doesn't that mean if i take the length of the set, i am just getting the total count the word appeared?

Comment: Based on the original question, that seemed to be what you wanted. You were summing the number of elements per `word + " " + fileName` key

Comment: Thats true, i see now it was wrong to get that key because in the result from the reduce function i am getting more outputs from the same word than i wanted.